# java sort if includes and then by abc

Tags: java, sorting

Hey I want to sort photo by name, first I want all photos that have the word "profile" in it, and then compare the rest by ABC

Currently I'm only sorting by name

```
            photos
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Photo::getFileName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How can I achieve that? thanks

Comment: Well, in that case you need to first map the name to 0 (contains "profile") or 1 (doesn't contain "profile") and sort by that (the mapping doesn't have to be done explicitly, you can also just return "contains profile is smaller than doesn't contain profile"). So what you need is to provide a custom field extractor (lambda) for the first `comparing` and put `Photo::getFileName` into the following `thenComparing(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write logic to determine an ordering "priority", with lower value be higher priority, e.g.

- 0 = contains "profile"
- 1 = everything else

Then sort by priority first, before you sort by name.

In the following example, we use regex for a case-insensitive "contains" check, and we pre-compile it for better performance.

```java
Pattern containsProfile = Pattern.compile("profile", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

photos.stream()
      .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Photo p) -> containsProfile.matcher(p.getFileName()).find() ? 0 : 1)
                        .thenComparing(Photo::getFileName))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own implementation of [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

Since your [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) contains `Photo` elements, you need a `Comparator` that compares `Photo` objects.

```java
Comparator<Photo> comparator = (Photo p1, Photo p2) -> {
    String p1Filename = p1.getFileName();
    String p2Filename = p2.getFileName();
    if (p1Filename.contains("profile") {
        if (p2Filename.contains("profile") {
            String tmp1 = p1Filename.replaceFirst("profile", "");
            String tmp2 = p2Filename.replaceFirst("profile", "");
            return tmp1.compareTo(tmp2);
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (p2Filename.contains("profile") {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return p1Filename.compareTo(p2Filename);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you just pass that `Comparator` to your stream operation.

```java
photos.stream()
      .sorted(comparator)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```java
photos.stream()
      .sorted((s1, s2) -> 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```